# posting results of a '*' SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code snippet:

```
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->store_result();

        echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=4>
        <tr bgcolor=white>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lname</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>email</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Lname']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Phone']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Address']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Discount']."</td>
            <td>".$row['email']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    $stmt->free_result();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

It's saying that mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. I've checked the query in myPHPadmin and it runs fine. I can't figure out why this wouldn't post.

Comment: what is the error?  Does it just not show any results?

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` with `mysql_*`.  They are distinctly different extensions, and cannot be mixed.

Comment: I don't know why you'd go through all the trouble of doing it this way when there are a number of frameworks designed to make this sort of routine thing a whole lot easier. Have you evaluated anything like [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) or even an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org)? Writing your own queries for everything is a technique from the 1990s that's been largely abandoned because it's error prone and time consuming.

Comment: It's funny this got closed. This is what they are teaching in my db class. They must want us to do it the hard way first.

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_fetch_array` is from the "mysql" extension, which is different from the "mysqli" extension that the rest of your code is using. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for complete examples of prepared statements in mysqli.

I think you want something like this (changes marked with `***`):

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$result = $stmt->get_result(); //***

    echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=4>
    <tr bgcolor=white>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Lname</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>email</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  //***
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Lname']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Phone']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Address']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Discount']."</td>
        <td>".$row['email']."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

$stmt->close(); //***

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I'm getting a fatal error for an undefined method with ->get_result()

Answer (score 2):

You're using a mysql_* function on a `mysqli` object, you need to use [`mysqli_result::fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()){
```

Comment: I'm also getting a fatal error for an undefined method with fetch_row()

Comment: @hobbes131 I might need to see more code, how is `$mysqli` assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question based on this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Not sure if it's the best style but it worked. Full php below

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $mysqli = new mysqli("***", "***", "***", "***");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";

        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($stmt)) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }

            echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=4>
            <tr bgcolor=white>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Lname</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>email</th>
            </tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['Name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Lname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Phone']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Address']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Discount']."</td>
                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

        $result->free();

    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```